# How to match types in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, pattern-matching

In F#, you can do this:

```ml
type DeliveredOrderData =
  {
    OrderId: int;
    DateDelivered: DateTime;
  }

type UndeliveredOrderData =
  {
    OrderId: int;
  }

type Order = 
  | Delivered of DeliveredOrderData
  | Undelivered of UndeliveredOrderData
```

and then I can create functions that return depending on the state:

```ml
let putOnTruck order = 
  match order with
    | Undelivered {OrderId=id} ->
      OutForDelivery {OrderId=id}
    | Delivered _ ->
      failwith "package already delivered"
```

I get how to create types in TypeScript, but how can I do the same as above?

```js
const putOrderOnTruck = (order: UndeliveredOrder) => {
  // how can I make sure order is really UndeliveredOrder?
}
```

Comment: Do you want to create a function that accepts as argument order id and returns a new function depending on that order id?

Comment: Does this help?  [TS docs on type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types).  Also look up "discriminated unions"

Answer (score 6):

The two main typescript concepts at play here are [Discriminating Unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) and [Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types).

We have two different types of order data.  The difference is that one has a `DateDelivered` and the other doesn't.  We can make that very explicit by saying that `UndeliveredOrderData` can `never` have a `DateDelivered` (ie. this property must not exist, or be set to `undefined`).

```
type DeliveredOrderData = {
    OrderId: number;
    DateDelivered: number;
  }

type UndeliveredOrderData = {
    OrderId: number;
    DateDelivered?: never;
}

type Order = DeliveredOrderData | UndeliveredOrderData
```

If we have an `Order` which could be either of the two types, we can tell which type it is by seeing if there is a `DateDelivered` or not.  We put that logic into a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) which tells typescript to narrow the type based on the result.

```
const isDelivered = (order: Order): order is DeliveredOrderData => {
    return !! order.DateDelivered;
}
```

Let's say we have a function that requires an `UndeliveredOrderData`

```
const doPutOnTruck = (order: UndeliveredOrderData) => {
}
```

But at runtime, we aren't sure if an `Order` is delivered or not.  We can use our type guard inside an `if` statement and act differently in the two branches.

```
const maybePutOnTruck = (order: Order) => {
  if ( isDelivered( order ) ) {
      throw new Error("package already delivered");
  }
  // type of `order` is now `UndeliveredOrderData`
  doPutOnTruck(order);
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhA2BLAbhAThAJgeTZ9MAhsIVALxQDeAsAFBQNS75oCSmAXFAHYCuAtgCN0AbjqNYxCHCSoMnHgOFox9KAF86dUJCgBVbvlnoszAsVIUaahmbYK%20Q0eMZFg0hChOYA-F24QcqqatNrg0HbksJ5ypnjmJFAAPvqGMd52boRatADGAPbcAM7AUIhFMl7yUQAU%20fFoXHYAlFz1LGVF0cbymRbkAHxULgwYwLxo3FAAhNNQ7egAdG4ePVjBOQXFpZj5AAq8wNjcACpovLkA1rULjalGVXEsWc2Dw7QhdFslUPyEIMIDkdTucrjcGk0Gq8yENrAxEAAzKA1TqVWKYFG3KCvV5wiRQYAACzQ%20QA7jwIOSAKJoEloGoAIjAhCuhAA5tBCPAMIRMCAoA90QzmqoGCEGAB6CUE8LzJEAA1u8s6PDJUHlBkFGQaWXlLl2QOOZwulzqUOCQA)

Comment: This solution has poor maintainability and scalability options. You never know how your objects will evolve in future, in case you will need to add DateDelivered property to UndeliveredOrderData (if business logic changes and you can deliver and then return order) then you cannot just add the property, but you will need to refactor your code.

Comment: @kihtov23 If you wanted the sort of flexibility that would allow you to deliver a package twice then it's inevitable that you're going to need additional data in your `Order` objects.  You could add an `orderStatus` property (like @Teneff's answer), an `isDeliverable` boolean, etc. 
 But that's not how I interpret this question.  This question is asking that we check that there is no `DateDelivered` property and refine the TypeScript type based on that.

Answer (score 4):

TypeScript's types can only be used for static type checking, so in order to do that you should check the object's properties.

Here is an example

```js
enum OrderType {
    Delivered,
    Undelivered
}

type DeliveredOrderData = {
    type: OrderType
    OrderId: number;
    DateDelivered: Date
}

type UndeliveredOrderData = {
    type: OrderType
    OrderId: number;
}

function OutForDelivery(order: UndeliveredOrderData) {
}

let putOnTruck = (orderData: DeliveredOrderData | UndeliveredOrderData) => {
    switch(orderData.type) {
        case OrderType.Undelivered: 
            return OutForDelivery(orderData);
        case OrderType.Delivered:
            throw new Error('package already delivered');
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably wanted to define `type` on (Un)DeliveredOrderData to be specific variants of `OrderType`, otherwise the "discriminating unions" magic does not kick in and the only reason you don't get an error is because TypeScript allows `DeliveredOrderData` instance to be passed to `OutForDelivery(order: UndeliveredOrderData)`. You can see that if you add a unique field to `UndeliveredOrderData`.

Comment: ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBA8gTgE2HAKgTwA7CgbwFBSFQAiwANgJYBuywCANAUQKohKU1x14C+eeAF0zZSHWgnhI4xAIYCZUALy4mhIVgBcsRMnRYAdKOriA3Ku1SAkgi3gIAI2RmiJOcCOc6W2QOC9+6tis7MZcEjrScgrK+C6BWpK6wvrB5KF0zkSJcNa2kI5wmYTAAB4CcDJaAM7lFCAA5mZ8eABmYCAAxgIUAPYgsGACAGI90mmcaAAUo1JaqWJh2T4yAJQqLh19VT1kwPpkPfXTEfql5av+eLsCUBiDMCAocGAdANZKUMdSy97j4ktRKAAHyg83S4W+UTWigAfOsiFUAO4UAQdAAWX2Qy30gTWsRcRA6Miq2Gyej2YM8Nig5gJRC4AjAcH6MEGIzGCymMyxUKKBKJJIsSQMHnEGlpdKgAjRcB6iKgIGA8oAonBZXBJgByDAyN4yerYGRkLgyBBoKAhKmalZ8vg8IA))

Answer (score 1):

Pattern matching is not an integral part of Typescript but you can substitute it with package [ts-pattern](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-pattern).

```
import { match, P } from "ts-pattern";

type Order =
  | { status: 'delivered'; orderId: number; dateDelivered: string }
  | { status: 'undelivered'; orderId: number; };

const putOnTruck = (order: Order) => {
  match(order)
    .with({status: 'delivered', dateDelivered: P.select()}, (dateDelivered, order) =>
       console.log(`Order ${order.orderId} has been delivered at ${dateDelivered}`))
    .with({status: 'undelivered'}, (order) =>
       console.log(`Order ${order.orderId} has not been delivered yet`))
    .exhaustive();
}
```